# A query regarding the definition of Polynomial Hierarchy and PSPACE

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

If a $\mathsf{PSPACE-Complete}$ problem (say $\mathsf{TQBF}$) has an algorithm that has the runtime $\mathsf{NP^{NP}}$ it follows that $\mathsf{PSPACE=\Sigma^P_2}$.

Does that also imply $\mathsf{\Sigma^P_2 = \Pi^p_2}$?
Moreover, does that imply $ \mathsf{\Delta^p_2\subset \Sigma^P_2}$ or is that question still open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PSPACE is closed under complementation, if $\mathsf{PSPACE} = \Sigma_2^P$ then
$$
\Sigma_2^P = \mathsf{PSPACE} = \mathsf{coPSPACE} = \mathsf{co}\Sigma_2^P = \Pi_2^P.
$$
We *always* have $\Delta_2^P \subseteq \Sigma_2^P$. I'm not sure if you can deduce the opposite inclusion under your assumption.

Comment: Thank you. I am unclear about the statement: "..opposite inclusion..". If I am correct it means that it cannot tell if the inclusion $\Delta_2^P \subseteq \Sigma_2^P$ is proper or not?

Comment: Given an inclusion $A \subseteq B$, the opposite inclusion is $B \subseteq A$.

Comment: I'm not sure how you would deduce $\Delta_2^P \neq \Sigma_2^P$; for all we know, it could be that P equals NP.

Comment: aah I understand. thank a lot.